# Monotouch/WCF: why cannot override the wcf binding timeout setting

Tags: wcf, xamarin.ios, timeout

Monotouch/WCF: why cannot override the wcf binding default timeout setting:

```
public class MyServiceClient : ClientBase<IMyContract>,IMyContract
{ ... }

public void test() {
        BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        basicHttpBinding.Name = "basicHttpBinding";
        basicHttpBinding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
        basicHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
        basicHttpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0);
        basicHttpBinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0);
        basicHttpBinding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0);
        basicHttpBinding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0);

       MyServiceClient client = New MyServiceClient(basicHttpBinding, new EndPointAddress(...));
       client.Test();
     }
```

// Althought I set the OpenTimeout to 5 seconds, but when I close the server service(or close the iphone's wifi & network), it still try to connect to the service in the background until the default 1 miniute timeout, it's strange! Why? thanks.

btw, the exception in monotouch/iPhone throw after 1 minutes,the type is TimeoutException(message:The operation has timed-out.) not the FaultException or CommunicationException). If the above code invoke in windows .net client, it should be throw the CommunicationException.

Comment: Does `MyServiceClient` also have timeout properties?

Comment: sorry, No , the clientbase hasn't this property.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

xamarin team reply: serviceClient.innerchannel.operationtimeout = ...
thanks.