# WCF Timeout Issue in iOS

Tags: c#, ios, wcf

I am using C# for ios application that I have been developing. I have a problem with timeout.

I followed at the following link 
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/

So this is my client helper

```
public class ClientHelper
{
    // DM Service Address
    private static readonly EndpointAddress EndPoint = new EndpointAddress("https://xxxxxxx/aaaaa/bbbbb.svc/basic");

    public static DMServiceClient CreateClient ()
    {
        var binding = CreateBasicHttp();

        return    new DMServiceClient(binding, EndPoint);
    }


    private static BasicHttpBinding CreateBasicHttp()
    {
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
        {
            Name = "BSHttpBinding",
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
            MaxBufferSize = 2147483647  
        };

        binding.ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
        {
            MaxArrayLength = 2147483646,
            MaxStringContentLength = 524288045

        };

        var timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
        binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
        binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
        binding.CloseTimeout = timeout;

        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
        return binding;
    }
}
```

Process can take more than 10 seconds and i set timeout as 2 seconds but not occured any exception.

We tried in desktop app and set it in appconfig file, it works. in iOS app, there is not appconfig file then i give timeout manualy like that.

Comment: What is the issue are u having a timeout ? since the process takes 10 seconds and you are specifying 2 seconds it won't work

Comment: I mean that timeoutexception doesnt occur even i set timeout as 2 seconds. For example, a process takes 10 seconds to complete, i gave 2 seconds as timeout, but it doesnt consider my timeout..

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.. Interesting, there is no information about it..

```
   service.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0);
```

so it solved my problem..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10108281/1022138